# How to bring up this widget panel via a Hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a function defined inside the current file, I can invoke `editor.action.showHover` through a hotkey to show the following pop up widget:

[image]

There is another pop up widget that pops up when I type `,` inside the functions `(...)`:

[image]

I would like to summon this second widget via a hotkey

I can only bring it up by typing a `,` inside the parenthesis. I often have to delete parts of my code and then type `,` just to bring it up as I don't have any other way to bring it up.

I don't know what this second widget is called so its hard to find its command. I tried checking the `default keyboard shortcuts.json` file for anything to do with "hover":

```
editor.action.showHover                    // Shows the pop up widget shown in the first gif file
editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover   // Identitical to the above command
editor.action.goToBottomHover              // Dont seem releveant       
editor.action.goToBottomHover              // Dont seem releveant    
editor.action.goToTopHover                 // Dont seem releveant 
editor.action.goToTopHover                 // Dont seem releveant 
editor.action.pageDownHover                // Dont seem releveant  
editor.action.pageDownHover                // Dont seem releveant  
editor.action.pageUpHover                  // Dont seem releveant
editor.action.pageUpHover                  // Dont seem releveant
editor.action.scrollDownHover              // Dont seem releveant    
editor.action.scrollLeftHover              // Dont seem releveant    
editor.action.scrollRightHover             // Dont seem releveant     
editor.action.scrollUpHover                // Dont seem releveant  
npm.debugScriptFromHover              
npm.runScriptFromHover
```

Is there a command for bringing up this widget?

Comment: It appears you want to `Trigger Parameter Hints` for which there is a default keybinding.  Closing as a duplicate - let me know if that wasn't what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mark Yes that is what I was looking for. It was a little hard to search without a name. Thanks.